# UIView's animateWithDuration delay not delaying animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, block, delay

I am trying to perform an animation on a label where a flip animation happens and after it is done and after a delay, The text of the label changes.

It seems that the delay never happens. The text immediately changes after the flip completes although I am using  `UIView animateWithDuration:0.5` **delay:4.0** in the completion block. If Instead I do a `performSelector` with Delay in the `completion block` (the commented statement) it works as expected. Any idea why the delay value is being ignored?

```
- (void) flipShapeWithText:(NSString *)text {

    [UIView transitionWithView:someLabel duration:0.15 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
        someLabel.text = text;  
    }completion:^ (BOOL finished){
//        [self performSelector:@selector(updateLabelText:) withObject: @"New Text" afterDelay:4.0];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:4.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                         animations:^{
                             currentShapeNameLabel.text =  @"New Text" ;}
                         completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `delay` param of `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion` specifies the delay before the animation occurs. You are setting the text within the animation block so after the delay is over, the animations begin which immediately changes the text as that change is not animatable. To do what you want, change the text in the completion block as follows:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:4.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                     animations:^{ // anything animatable }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         currentShapeNameLabel.text =  @"New Text" ;}];
```

You can eliminate the delay if you want the animation to start immediately. If you want the text change to happen 4 secs after the animation completes add that delay in the completion block either with `dispatch_after()` or `performSelector:withDelay:`.

Comment: FYI: Setting nil as the argument for the animations block is illegal -- according to the current state of Apple's documentation, at least.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the problem was that earlier in the code I was calling `UIView`'s `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` with a value `true`. After changing that to `false` it worked fine.

Comment: I had this same problem, and you saved me a bit of time with the debugging, so thanks :).  In my case I couldn't set this value to false, so I just use dispatch_after to perform this particular animation and it worked fine.

Comment: Thats pretty obscure. Good catch.

Answer (score -1):

try nesting in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
});
```

Comment: Try to provide more details with you answer about how it solves the OP question.